# Custom Gradle Task Fails - Can't Find GitPush

Tags: git, groovy, push, task, gradle

I'm trying to push to a remote git repo in a Gradle task. The best way I've found is to use the plugin Gradle-Git found here: https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git

I'm basically just trying to be able to run the push task and then go from there configuring it to be used in my project.

Here's what my build.gradle script looks like.

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'base'

import org.ajoberstar.gradle.git.tasks.*

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "[my custom repository repo]"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.ajoberstar:gradle-git:0.4.0' 
}

task push(type: GitPush) {
    println "Test"
}
```

and my error is

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '[my_path]\build.gradle' line: 19

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Name'.
> Could not find property 'GitPush' on root project 'Name'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

and running with --stacktrace produces the exception logs here: http://pastebin.com/uqjf5U5k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't followed the instructions on the plugin site

To add something to the build itself, you need to have a `buildscript` block

```
buildscript {
  repositories { mavenCentral() }
  dependencies { classpath 'org.ajoberstar:gradle-git:0.4.0' }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! I assumed that since I already had repositories and dependencies blocks that I could add the lines to those sections instead of creating a separate buildscript block.